# Do I need to put Factory calls inside a function in my Controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Most of the time I will call in a Factory from my Angular controller, but I'll just leave it in the controller function and not in its own function. Like this for example:

```
    (function () {
      'use strict';

      angular.module("Dashboard")
      .controller("DashboardController", DashboardController);

      DashboardController.$inject = ["Interface"];

      function DashboardController (Interface)
      {
        var vm = this;


        /**
         * Total Open Tickets
         */
        Interface.openTickets().then(function (data) {
            vm.tickets = objCount(data);
          });
      }

    })();
```

I'll always need to see the total amount of open tickets in my view so I don't really need to have another function for it. But would it be more effective and improve code readability to put the `Interface` call in another method and then initialize all the methods? 
Like this:

```
    function DashboardController (Interface)
    {
      var vm = this;
      vm.getTickets = getTickets();

      /**
       * Total Open Tickets
       */
      function getTickets() {
        Interface.openTickets().then(function (data) {
            vm.tickets = objCount(data);
          });
      }

    }
```

I'm thinking the second example is the cleaner way to do it, so I'm thinking about updating all of my code. Am I right in thinking this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I think this is the cleanest way to write it. This comes down to personal preference for the most part. I would avoid a self invoking function, as it clutters things up, and if you use angular.module you don't introduce any globals. I would avoid C-style brackets, as the auto-injection of semicolons in javascript can mess this up in some cases. I can't remember the exact case, but I know Crockford mentions it in his "Javascript, the good parts". If you won't use getTickets for anything else but to call another function, then I think it just clutters up the code. Just say in the comment what happens.

```
angular.module("Dashboard")
  .controller("DashboardController", function DashboardController (Interface) {
    var vm = this;

    /**
     * Get Total Open Tickets
     */
    Interface.openTickets().then(function (data) {
        vm.tickets = objCount(data);
      });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the C Style bracket call out. Wasn't aware of that